# orderByDescending("createdAt") Parse query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i am trying to give an order to the retrieved data from parse.com using `orderByDescending("createdAt")` . My code looks like:

```
 var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")              
     postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedUser)           
     postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")  
     postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects, error) -> Void in

         if let objects = objects {

                 for object in objects {
                            println(object.createdAt)
                     if let post = object as? PFObject {

                          self.data.addObject(object)
```

but it isn't working.. The data comes in a random order. 
`println(object.createdAt` gives:

```
Optional(2015-08-25 22:25:36 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-24 13:39:25 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-25 22:28:28 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-24 13:40:48 +0000)
```

my full code is:

```
  func loadData() {

    var followersQuery : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

    followersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    followersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let followers = objects {

            for users in followers {

                var followedUserId = users["user"] as! String

                    println(followedUserId)

                var postQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                    postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
                    postQuery.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: followedUserId)
                postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                    if let objects = objects {

                        for object in objects {

                            println(object.createdAt)

                            self.data.addObject(object)

                           // println(self.data)

                        }

                    }
                })

            }

        }


    }


}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see a problem in your Parse query. How do you check the order? Can you add a "println(object.createdAt)" below "for object in objects" and check again?

Comment: Thanks for reply.i've edited the question. @Peter Fennema

Comment: Yes, the problem now shows clear. Some trial and error now: Could you comment out the line with the whereKey and check the ordering of the result?

Comment: That's giving me the required result. :/ `Optional(2015-08-25 22:31:12 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-25 22:28:28 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-25 22:25:36 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-24 13:40:48 +0000)
Optional(2015-08-24 13:39:25 +0000)
so why is that error in loop?? `

Comment: I think that the solution is that you have to apply the whereKey AFTER  the orderByDescending instead of BEFORE. So in your code you should exchange the 2 lines. Can you check if I'm right?

Comment: i've edited my question. see my full code.

Comment: same result, do you mean still random order?

Comment: yes. the same i got from println()

Comment: I'm out of ideas for the moment, I'll think about it, or hope someone else comes up with a solution

Comment: Kind of odd. I have similar code working as intended.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I think theres a bug where you cannot use a where clause along with an orderBy key. Well so it seems, as Ive been trying to figure out a workaround